# Can we install docker/podman inside a container and run dokcer commands from inside the jar which is deployed on that container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, podman, oraclelinux

I tried exploring a lot then from bits and pieces I was able to succeed in getting podman installed as by checking from inside the pod I was able to fetch podman --version.
But the main problem remained as is since I had to use docker pull , it gives error -

WARN[0000] "/" is not a shared mount, this could cause issues or missing mounts with rootless containers
ERRO[0000] running `/usr/bin/newuidmap 279 0 54321 1 1 100000 65536`: newuidmap: write to uid_map failed: Operation not permitted
Error: cannot set up namespace using "/usr/bin/newuidmap": should have setuid or have filecaps setuid: exit status 1

In Dockerfile I have used -

```
FROM phx.ocir.io/oraclegbudevcorp/cn-fsgbu-erfplatform/oraclelinux:8-slim
RUN 
microdnf install -y podman && \
microdnf install -y podman-docker && \
chmod 777 /usr/bin/newgidmap && \
chmod 777 /usr/bin/newuidmap && \
```

Please suggest how the docker/podman would be available inside the container for running docker commands as I am using oraclelinux:8 image as reference.

Comment: Even if this is technically possible, I'd advise against trying this.  With standard Docker, it's all but trivial to use the Docker socket to take over the entire host.  This approach also won't work on other container environments like Kubernetes.  If you do need to programmatically invoke Docker, using a Docker SDK will be more robust than trying to call the `docker` CLI.

Comment: @DavidMaze could you share more details or maybe exact piece of code which I can use, sorry but I have less knowledge on this stuff

Comment: What's your end goal with this?  Why do you think you need Docker inside the container?  (Is there another way to do this, without needing the permissions and Docker-specific setup?)

Comment: Basically I have to pull an external image using docker pull and then docker tag which has to be done under the JAVA API which is containerized and when I try doing that from inside the pod, it says docker command not found.